# SQLPLUS Records not correctly showing

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am currently trying to create a report using SQLPLUS, but the output keeps splitting after showing record #11.

[image: SQLPLUS Output]

I would like to see all the records under one output. The second columns 'Schema' and 'TOTAL_SIZE_IN_GB' are unnecessary and I want to get rid of them. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
set verify off
set feedback off
column owner format a15 heading 'Schema'
column total_size format 990.99 heading 'TOTAL_SIZE_IN_GB'

SELECT owner, ROUND(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024/1024, 2) total_size
  FROM dba_segments
 where (segment_type='TABLE' and owner like '%OBS%')
 or (segment_type='TABLE' and owner like '%USR%')
group by owner
 order by total_size DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many rows are shown "per page" is controlled by a setting, `pagesize`. (This is all SQL*Plus stuff, it has nothing to do with the query itself.) Issue the following SQL*Plus command before you run your query:

```
set pagesize 3000
```

(or some other number larger than the number of rows in your output).

Obviously, if you have 10000 rows in the output they will still be broken into "pages" of 3000 rows each, but I hope you are not actually creating a report, for human reading, with 10000 rows. No one will read that.

You could also set the pagesize to zero, but then you won't print column headers anymore; likely not what you need.